# Region of integration

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals

If i have the region: $$W=\left\{ \left( x,y\right) \in \mathbb{R} ^{2}:0\leq y\leq x\leq 1\right\} $$

And the random vector $(X,Y)$ with the following joint PDF:

$$ \begin{equation}
  f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)= \left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    c(x^4 + y^2), & \text{if}\ \left( x,y\right) \in W \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation} $$

I want to find $c$

And I think one way of do the integration is like this:

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1} c(x^4+y^2)dxdy = 1$

This would give me $c= \frac{15}{8}$

also i can try like this $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x} c(x^4+y^2)dxdy = 1$

And in this case it gives me $c=4$

Where is the mistake?

Comment: I gave you the answer below, but you define a PDF and then take other PDF.

Comment: Sorry was a mistake of input, i just correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look at first integral, the limits of integration are ok, but calculate is wrong. The value of $c$ is 4

Seconde, the limits in second integration are wrong. If you want to change the order of integration, then $x\in[0,1]$ and $y\in[0,x]$: $\int_0^1\int_0^xc(x^4+y^2)dydx=1$ yielding again $c=4$

Comment: Hi, i try  $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1} c(x^4+y^2)dydx = 1$ and then $c \int_{0}^{1} (x^4 y +\frac{y^3}{3})dx = 1$ (y to 1) -> $c \int_{0}^{1} (x^4 1 +\frac{1^3}{3} - (y^5 + \frac{y^3}{3}))dx = 1$ ?

Comment: No. The inner integral that you wrote doesn't have sense. Particulary $\int_y^1y^2dy$ doesn't. Check the first integral that you wrote in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Your first apporach is ok but I think you've got the value of $c$ wrong, but this expression is not really well defined:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\color{red}{x}} c(\color{red}{x^4}+y^4)\color{red}{dx}dy$$

Have you tried calculating

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x} c(x^4+y^4)dydx$$

(which should yield the same result that you had in your first approach)